# How to reorder divs based on class names using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="subscriptionContainer">

<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="subscribed">Subscribed</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="btnGetit">Get It</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="subscribed">Subscribed</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="btnGetit">Get It</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="subscribed">Subscribed</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="subscription">
  <div class="subs-btn">
        <div class="btnGetit">Get It</div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Now I want to rearrange the "subscription" divs withing the "subscriptionContainer" such that the divs that have class = "subscribed" should be moved to bottom and the divs having class = "btnGetit" should all be moved up. Please give solutions in Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Just for the sake of learning, can anybody provide me a pure JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var $wrap = $('#subscriptionContainer');
$wrap.find('.subscribed').parents('.subscription').appendTo( $wrap );
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ebudux/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript implementation that I finally worked out

```
var container = document.getElementById('subscriptionContainer');
var allDivs = container.getElementsByTagName('div');
var subsProds = new Array();
var count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++)
{
    var currentElement = allDivs[i];
    if (currentElement.className == 'subscribed') {
        subsProds[count] = currentElement.parentNode.parentNode;
        container.removeChild(currentElement.parentNode.parentNode);
        count++;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < subsProds.length; i++)
    container.appendChild(subsProds[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $wrap = $('#subscriptionContainer');
$wrap.find('.subscription').children('.subscribed').appendTo( $wrap );
```